# If Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne method call blocks the thread, we can’t do anything on that thread. How can we use it for cancellation then?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = cts.Token;
Task.Run(() => {
  while(true){
    //Doing something in the loop
    token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(); // Method 1
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); // Method 2
  }
}, token);
```

Out of these two methods of cancelling a Task, Method 2 is what I understand. But, Method 1 is posing a problem in my understanding, because what I read is it blocks the execution. If it is a blocking call, that means our code is not executing. Then how can this be a method of cancellation? To cancel means, a running task is cancelled, where as in this case when we are waiting, the task is already not executing our code.

Comment: Where did this code come from - if you found it in documentation, an article, etc it may help to link back to it. I'm sure it has more context than just saying "here are two methods", which is all the context *you're* giving us.

Comment: Why do you think method 1 would be useful for cancellation?

Comment: `token.WaitHandle.WaitOne();` blocks until someone call `cts.Cancel()` on **another** thread

Comment: It was a course lecture on udemy. I understood it incorrectly. Actually, it was used to monitor if a Task is cancelled and to execute some code in that case. Thank you for your comments.